View binary data of large file
I have a file of about 7GB containing binary information. The file type is custom.
How can I view the binary data, preferably in hex form?
Opening it in Notepad or VS code does not work, because the file is too large.
The windows cmd command  -encodehex myFile.sData out.txt does not work either.
The powershell command format-hex myFile.sData | more does not work either.

https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/
